# Change user data automatically whether he is online or offline with php

Tags: php

For Example - When a user signup he get 100 scores and its score automatically increase by 1 every second whether he is online or offline with php mysqli
and updates to database.
I want to increase his score if he is offline and logout.

Happy New Year To All.

Thanks

Comment: To achieve this you can use jquery and ajax. call a function/page in php using ajax after each second. That php function can increment in database.
When user is offline that ajax call will be failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider to use WebSocket to know whether the user is online more accurately, and the server-side program just need to calculate the scores when the user's state changed. 
Also, frameworks like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) is easy to build implement WebSockets.
If you want to use PHP for handling WebSocket on server-side, [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) is a good tool for you.